# Tabletop heist game

Tags: identify-this-game

I don't remember a thing about the name but here is what I remember from playing:

- The stats/ability side of character creation was done with 3 cards (probably have the names wrong) a family, a class, and a quirk, ex: my character was a gravedigger thief with some quirk that allowed me to heal.
- The game was set when guns were just becoming a thing.
- It seemed somewhat wargamey as the GM would gain heat tokens if we did suspicious stuff.
- Actions would use a d100 and you would have to hit below a number designated by class.
- There were day and night phases (only got to play one day and one night) where during the day we would plan and during night we would do footwork ex: gathering information, murder, casings, and theft.
- You had 100 luck which you could spend to add to your roll but it was also your hp.
- The other 2 people in the party were an _____ assassin who was a failed alchemy apprentice as quirk and a vodok? brawler ______.

That's all the information I remember, thank you for taking your time to read.

i dont know how to say its answered as im new to this site but ATCOlogy got the game, thanks for that https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/51616/32773

Comment: [I directed this user here based on a much terser description of a game they played on Tabletop Simulator.] Is this based on a board game or an RPG? I can't really tell by your description. I may have guided you to the wrong site of this network.

Comment: Going to bed. [This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) is the RPG site if that's more appropriate.

Comment: Re "*i dont know how to say its answered*", You click the checkmark next to the answer you like :)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like [Dusk City Outlaws](https://scratchpadpublishing.com/dco-info), a tabletop RPG from Scratchpad Publishing, which is available on Tabletop Simulator according to the publisher's website. Gravediggers are a character type in the game, and the other mechanics you describe (heat tokens, percentile-based skill rolls based on your class, day- and night-based phases, luck serving as HP and a way to modify rolls) would also fit. A video example of play is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxhMfa-rn2I).